# How do I setup a working TensorFlow environment on my Windows 11 PC, utilizing Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, machine-learning

On my modified HP Z820 (Beast) Windows 11 PC, running two Zeon processors, I have been searching for a while, trying to build a Python Data Science Development Environment to run Tensorflow on my NVIDIA CTX 3060 GPU for Machine Learning.

There were several failed attempts, where the GPU was not getting detected. Finally, I discovered a Docker Solution, which provides pre-build Tensorflow Containers that run on WSL2.  That was very rewarding to know that other developers had the same issue and a Docker Solution came to the rescue. After a couple of weeks, I was able to piece together a few resources that provided a working component of each of my required areas.

My first resource was found on the Docker, Tensorflow web page, which referenced a docker run command with Nvidia support.

```
docker run -it --rm --runtime=nvidia tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu python
```

An error was generated about the --runtime=nvidia variable.  I kept looking and found a Google search, indicating that a new variable was required for the current docker version.  The modified, working call looks like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus all tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu python
```

This call loaded with a Python interpreter, which tested properly:

```
print(f"Keras Version: {keras.__version__}")
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

I was very happy to see the response:

```
Tensor Flow Version: 2.12.0
GPU is available
```

Nevertheless, having the proper Docker was not enough for my requirements.  I still need my development environment UI, and Microsoft was able to provide a Docker/VSCode solution.
[Use a Docker container as a development environment with Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/use-docker-container-dev-env-vs-code/)

I am looking for some assistance/guidance or pointers in bridging these two solutions together, resulting in a Docker Development Environment that runs on my Windows 11 PC that supports Tensorflow and all the required Data Science/Machine Learning features, such as Pandas, numpy, Matplotlib, etc...